# How to set django upload_handler in admin?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-admin

I'm trying to make a django upload progress bar within the django admin.
The application is only a small part of the project, therefor I do not want to set the custom upload handler in the settings.py.

The upload_handler can be set with `request.upload_handlers.insert(0, UploadProgressHandler(request))` but not within the add_view of the django admin class.
The response is this exception:

> If you try to modify request.upload_handlers after reading from
>   request.POST or request.FILES Django will throw an error.

I also tried doing this with a decorator over the `add_view` but then I do not know how to access the `request.upload_handlers`.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source for the decorator that comes with the admin app:

```
def staff_member_required(view_func):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in and is a staff
    member, displaying the login page if necessary.
    """
    @wraps(view_func)
    def _checklogin(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff:
            # The user is valid. Continue to the admin page.
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The decorator 'wraps' the original view so you are able to check the request arg before calling the original view func with it.

Comment: For quick reference, here is the module mentioned: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.10/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py